# Java program is still running. How to stop?

Tags: java

I wrote an application for using a sftp-client.

In the main method, I am calling a method which downloads a file from a sftp server. When the file is downloaded, the program is still running. How can I stop it?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    downloadFile();
}
```

Comment: You should probably show the code for "downloadFile()".

Comment: Please also debug your code inside `downloadFile()` and tell us on which line of code it hangs up.

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.exit(0)` when download is completed, inside the `downloadFile()` method.

*Sidenote*: Make sure you dispose resources and close buffers before doing so.

Comment: Note: While this technically works, this maybe give unexpected results if the nio (?) Channel isn't closed properly. :) Would probably be better to figure out why downloadFile() hangs (or loops) indefinitely.

Comment: What happens if you do not dispose resources properly and exit?

Comment: I don't like exiting a process that way, especially not if you're using it to not have to shut down threads properly.

Comment: I doubt that the OP has a complex process in the `downloadFile()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your code for downloadFile() method. If that method has some io stream then close and flush them. After that you can call System.exit(). But keep in mind it will not resume execution once System.exit() is called. I think it is better to share your downloadFile() method definition because there must be something wrong in that method that's why its not returning and exiting the execution.

Answer (score 0):

It is my downloadfile() code. I'm using zehon library.

```
public static int downloadFile() { //upload do serwera SFTP
            String sftpFolder = "/Kursy"; 
            String nameOfFile = "Kursy.txt"; 
            String toLocalFolder = "C:/DATA/work_dir"; 
            int status = -1;  
            String test=null;
            if (localfileExists()<sftpfileExists()) {
                try { 
                    SFTPClient sftpClient = new SFTPClient("127.0.0.1", "test", "test");  //polaczenie do servera SFtp              

                status = sftpClient.getFile(nameOfFile, sftpFolder, toLocalFolder); 
                 System.out.println("downloaded");
                } catch (Exception e) { 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
                }

            } else {
                 System.out.println("Daty sa takie same");
            }

            return status;

        }
```

Comment: now, i puted System.exit(0) before return status; and it's work :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a boolean.

```
public static boolean downloadFile() {

  if(statement){
   //when it works or finish the process that u want
           return true;

  }

  return true;

  }
```